# Query to create a dropdown list from two tables having same column name in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables student and employee having same column as location I want to write a query in spark sql to create a dropdown list for location column which should have records from both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the `location` column from both tables separately and then merge them using `union`.

```
val employees:DataFrame = ... //read from employees table
val students:DataFrame = ... //read from students table
val locations:DataFrame = employees.select("location").union(students.select("location")).dropDuplicates
```

Reading from JDBC is done like this (taken from the [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)):

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()
```

Comment: val employee:DataFrame = sqlContext.read.df.select('location').collect()
val student:DataFrame = sqlContext.read.df.select('location').collect() is it a correct way?it is throwing error: unclosed character literal
       val employee:DataFrame = sqlContext.read.df.select('location').collect()